# Display error when apache2 server is offline?

Tags: html, apache, raspberry-pi4

I'm wondering if there's a way to get a custom error or web page when my **apache2** server is offline. I use the **Raspberry Pi** for it, (running apache2). Is there any way to make it so that when it's offline, your computer would display a certain HTML file? Maybe there's a way to make it so that when you first go to the page, it will download that HTML file with a bit of code telling the computer to display it if there's a 404 error (or whatever error you would get)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to hook up a Raspberry Pi Zero W (~$10) so that it would take requests from the users. Then it would make a query to the official server. If it didn't get a response, then it would send the custom error page.